# ModelMap/ModelAndView data is not displayed

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, el

I am trying to run spring mvc helloworld example by [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_hello_world_example.htm).but I am not geeting the modelmap data in jsp page .I had added all the required jars in web-inf/lib folder.I am also using `<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" isELIgnored="false" %>` .But still i am not getting data in jsp page. i also view so many answers for this question on stackoverflow and on http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/modelandviews-model-value-is-not-displayed-in-jsp-via-el/ 
this is my project flow.Please help Thanks in advance

.[image]
And my HelloController is

```
package com.tutorialspoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController{

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

      return "hello";
   }

}
```

web.xml is ::

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

HelloWeb-servlet.xml is

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

and this is my hello.jsp::

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" isELIgnored="false" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
 hiiiii <h2>${message}</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exception or any error you got?

Comment: @Rembo.. I am not getting the value in jsp using expression language "${message}" which i was setting in HelloController using "      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");" this...

Comment: change web app xsd schema to 3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue . there was some problem with structure what i made.Thanks @akfaz..we have to make a jsp folder inside web-inf then have to write hello.jsp for this code...here is a screen sort of my current project flow which is working fine and i am able to get data of ModelMap/Model& view in jsp using spring MVC.:) 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Normally the application will look for the folder `webapp` (located in `src/main/webapp/`), there You should move the whole WEB-INF folder with the corresponding `jsp` files (`src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp`).

However the tutorial You using (`tutorialspoint`) assumes copying of the whole WEB-INF to the webapp folder in tomcat - with corresponding libs (

> Once you are done with creating source and configuration files, export your application. Right click on your application and use Export > WAR File option and save your HelloWeb.war file in Tomcat's webapps folder.

For future I strongly suggest using build automation tool like maven, which will ease the process [spring mvc with maven](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/).

Comment: Thanks....for you answer.....But i am not geeting what you are saying.. do i have to move hello.jsp in webapp .??? all the jars are already there in web-app library

Comment: if You want to do this manually, You need to copy whole WEB-INF dir to web-app in tomcat (or whatever You're using)

Comment: I am using Tomcat 8.. Did you mean to say that i have to place web-inf dir to web-app of tomcat i.e(C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.9\webapps) here.. but how this is going to do effect i am not able to understand...

Comment: **Thanks @ akfaz **. I solved this issue . there was some problem with structure what i made.Thanks @akfaz..we have to make a jsp folder inside web-inf then have to write hello.jsp for this code.<br>

Answer (score 0):

change web.xml xsd schema from 2.4 to 3 like:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    metadata-complete="true" version="3.0">
```

Comment: #Rembo Thanks for Reply...I tried above code change in web.xml but still i not not getting the data in jsp which i am setting in controller using modelMap..:(